# Gerando identificador único utilizando time()

Tags: php, mysql, algoritmo

Criei um algoritmo para gerar um identificador, que consistem em um valor aleatório com 24 caráteres não sequencial. O objetivo basicamente é capturar a hora atual usando `time()` e concatenar com notas musicais(letras de 'a' a 'g'). haha

#### Algoritmo:

```
<?php
    $reduce = substr(date('YmdHis', time()), 2);
    $arr_date = str_split($reduce);
    $arr1 = str_split("cdefgab");
    $uid = "";
    for($i = 0; $i<12; $i++){
        $uid .= $arr1[rand(0, 6)];
        $uid .= $arr_date[$i];
    }
    echo $uid;
```

Veja funcionando [aqui no ideone](http://ideone.com/km3fqh).

#### Resultado:

```
e1d6e1c2e1g1g0f8f5f4a2a0
```

Pretendo usar esse valor como `ID` único com chave privada em uma tabela de usuários no meu banco de dados MySQL. Basicamente é criar um `ID` único(não sequencial) no lugar de um `ID` único inteiro que auto incrementa (sequencial) numa tabela de usuários.

Gostaria de saber se usando este algoritmo haveria alguma problema futuro ou se existe algo que torne essa minha solução inviável?

Comment: Basicamente está desperdiçando entropia. 24 bytes podem armazenar até 192 bits de informação. Seu algoritmo gera aproximadamente 60 bits de informação, o que é pouco para o tamanho da string. Para fins de comparação, mesmo que precisasse de algo legivel por um humano, se usasse 16 bytes em base 64, para dar os 24 caracteres, já teria ao menos 128 bits, o que é absurdamente muito menos chance de colisão que seu método. Tudo bem que 60 bits ainda é um set bastante extenso de possibilidades, mas à medida que for tendo mais e mais registros, a chance de colisão aumenta.

Comment: Na verdade, é melhor ainda. Em 24 caracteres base 64 cabem 18 bytes, não só 16. O que dá 136 bits, e não 128 como eu mencionei anteriormente..

Comment: @Bacco (rs sumiu o chat) Na verdade, na verdade eu não entendi o que você disse que "...é melhor ainda". Você está sugerindo usar TO_BASE64 é isso?

Comment: Eu marquei como obsoleto, pra moderação limpar pq estava ficando muita informação já resolvida no post. Quis dizer que se você usar base 64, pode usar até 18 bytes completamente aleatórios, ou seja, uma variedade razoável de combinações. Se fizer uma sequência de 24 caracteres com rand(0, 63), sendo os 63 caracteres da base 64 (ou os que escolher no lugar destes), dá 136 bits de informação. (2,23 * 10^43 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que pode afirmar sobre o código apresentado é que a cada século as chances de colisão serão maiores pois está cortando os dois primeiros números referente ao ano.

A função `date()` formata a data e hora (*2016-12-11 08:54:20*), resultando nisso: `20161211085420`

Na sequência remove os dois primeiros números, ficando assim: `161211085420`

Aqui temos um pequeno problema pois quando chegar no ano 2116, daqui a 100 anos, terá mais chances de colisões mesmo embaralhando randomicamente com letras de A a G (ABCDEFG), que aliás, é pouco para garantir maiores combinações. Claro, é ridiculo se preocupar com isso, mas já que perguntou onde teria algum problema. Basicamente deve pensar em chances óbvias de colisão.

No seu exemplo, gerou isso: `e1d6e1c2e1g1g0f8f5f4a2a0` e é muito fácil de entender a sequência apenas removendo as letras.

Você pode argumentar que 100 anos é muito tempo, ninguém aqui estará vivo e provavelmente o sistema que está criando nem será usado, além do mais será usado para cadastro de usuários e não para gerar grandes quantidades de IDs ao mesmo tempo. Mas mesmo sob essa justificativa ainda está criando algo que não mascara a sequência muito bem. Qualquer pessoa sem conhecimento em progamação consegue entender a sequência e que se trata de uma data.

Se formos apontar um "problema" e como a intenção parece ser mascarar a sequência, acredito ser relevante colocar isso em pauta.

Sob esse contexto, focarei na mascaração da sequência. Então a pergunta que faço é, por que não usar o próprio valor do timestamp?

E se ainda quiser "embaralhar" pode apenas converter em letras.

Normalmente utilizo isso:

```
$id = microtime();
$a = explode(' ', $id);
$a[0] = str_replace('.', '', $a[0]);
$a[0] = base_convert($a[0], 10, 36);
$a[1] = base_convert($a[1], 10, 36);
echo $id.' -> '.$a[0].$a[1];
```

Retorna algo assim: `0.70350700 1481537805 -> 15vuy4oi2hvx`

Esse primeiro, `0.70350700 1481537805`, é o valor retornado da função `microtime()`.

Removo o caracter ponto (.), separo os dois números e converto cada um com base_convert().

```
070350700 -> 15vuy4
1481537805 -> oi2hvx
```

No final, o resultado convertido é concatenado, resultando nesse ID: **15vuy4oi2hvx**

É metade do espaço que ocuparia com o que apresentou na pergunta:  `e1d6e1c2e1g1g0f8f5f4a2a0` e ainda um pouco mais "eficiente" em relação a colisões por concatenar o microtime ao timestamp além do fato de não se preocupar com a data, a menos que o ambiente onde execute tenha uma data configurada errada para um valor no passado cujas datas já possuam códigos gerados. São possibilidades ridículas, mas é possível acontecer.

Comparando o tempo de execução,

Script da pergunta: 0.0000128746032714844

Script do exemplo acima: 0.0000109672546386719

Não é algo tão relevante, portanto a vantagem maior é a string final que ocuparia metade do espaço.

De uma forma geral, não há problema algum no que apresentou na pergunta, dadas as condições. Mas achei que seria proveitoso demonstrar uma outra lógica que acredito ser um pouco melhor por gerar uma string mais econômica.

Comment: Tinha ciência de que "...cada século as chances de colisão serão maiores...", e desta forma ia exatamente argumentar "...que 100 anos é muito tempo...". Na questão da sequência, não consigo enxergar nenhum problema pois esse ID não é algum tipo de código de acesso que seria quebrado de alguma forma, mas teu formato me interessou. Bom, deve ter perguntado como cheguei nesta pergunta?! Dando uma olhada no JSON que o [Trello disponibiliza](https://trello.com/b/XVOTxCht.json), percebi que eles usam como identificador uma sequencia de 192bits e fiquei curioso, daí então comecei a questionar isso.

Comment: Na sua sugestão de solução, SEMPRE retornará um valor de 96bits?

Comment: É esperado que sim pois timestamp é sempre 10 dígitos e microtime, 9. Desde que use base 36.

Comment: Vou fazer mais alguns testes, algumas pesquisas e valido sua resposta que por cima foi muito útil pra mim. Obrigado.

Comment: Daniel, fiz alguns teste para validar sua ideia. Cheguei numa situação, mas não sei se de fato me trará um problema. No seu algoritmo hora me retorna um valor com 96bits, hora me retorna com 88bits; Percebi que atingiu cerca de uns 65% para 11 caracteres, e o restante com 12 caracteres. Alguma coisa errada não está certa! eheh No meu banco, quero dar preferência que uma coluna tenha um tamanho fixo todo preenchido. Tipo VARCHAR(12) que sempre contenha exatamente 12 caracteres.

Comment: Normalmente eu não defino tamanho fixo. Defino como `CHAR(20)` mas se pretende tamanho fixo, não se pode confiar no método apresentado aqui. Terá que considerar algo como MD5, SHA, etc. Mas só o MD5 em si já ocupa um espaço "monstro" de 32 caracteres para essa finalidade. Mas afinal, porque se preocupa em ter um tamanho fixo? E poderia mostrar exemplos desses casos que encontrou tamanho diferente?

Comment: Verdade, talvez eu não tenha que preocupar com tamanho fixo. Mas acha que posso então usar um coluna do tipo TEXT?! Só mais essa pra fechar a questão.

Comment: Coluna TEXT é grande demais. Desperdício de espaço. Eu aplico char 20 para dar uma margem segura. Note que não uso VARCHAR que aloca mais espaço. Aplico o simples CHAR. (Falando do MySQL)

Comment: Meu caso seria MySQL utilizando sync com SQLite.